# EntityDataSource Control get DataSource Manual

Tags: c#-4.0, entity-framework-4, entitydatasource

Shouldn't we be able to ise the DataSource Controls and append data to it from our Data Repository Class Library instead of using declarative the controls but using them with our own select, insert, update, delete methods? Something similar with BindingSource in Windows Forms!

In specific i use the entity framework in a Data Model Class and a Class Library having all the data access methods using the for a Web Client Application project, so I need to handle or the data commands from my class.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In such case don't use EntityDataSource - it doesn't allow you using your own data access class. Use [ObjectDataSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9a4kyhcx.aspx) instead where you can define your own data access class and provide methods for select, insert, update and delete.